# Como utilizar o IDLE dentro de um ambiente virtual?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Quando instalamos o Python ele instala automaticamente uma IDLE junto, mas ao criar um Ambiente Virtual ele não instala. Como faço para ter acesso ao IDLE dentro de um ambiente virtual?

Comment: Votei para reabrir a pergunta. Sinceramente não entendi o motivo dos votos negativos nem do fechamento. Para mim é uma pergunta perfeitamente válida.

Answer (score 4):

Não precisa instalar. O IDLE na verdade é um módulo que vem junto com o Python e, quando criado o ambiente virtual, continua disponível para você.

Para executá-lo, basta criar e ativar o seu ambiente virtual:

```
$ python -m venv venv
$ source ./venv/bin/activate
```

Depois executar o IDLE a partir da linha de comando:

```
(venv) $ python -m idlelib.idle
```

Assim, você executará o módulo `idle` do pacote `idlelib`, que é responsável pelo IDLE em si.

<sub>Exemplo no Windows com Python 3.9.1:</sub>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]